# relative src and href paths work live but not local

Tags: html, css, href, local, src

I was making a new path for pages on my site and was trying to figure out how to path to my stylesheet and images cleanly. Here's an element that shows my problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/styles.css">
```

My local copy of my site is hosted here at "E:/Documents/WEBSITE", the local page I'm trying to link the stylesheet from is "file:///E:/Documents/WEBSITE/things/weapons.html", and the stylesheet is at "E:/Documents/WEBSITE/src/styles.css". I have the local site open on Firefox and I am using VSC to code. When I follow the href path in VSC, it brings me to the correct stylesheet. When I upload a version of the site that has the same path, it works correctly.
I have the local site open on Firefox and I am using VSC to code. When I follow the href path in VSC, it brings me to the correct stylesheet.

I've looked over the code and made sure it would(and does) work otherwise. Like I said, it works when on the live site.
I've placed dummy "src" folders with "styles.css" in them on my base E drive, my Documents folder, and even in the "things" folder itself. If the href were pulling from any one of these, there would be an obvious change to the local site, but none of them are pulled from with that path.
When I upload a version of the site that has the same path, it works correctly. The same happens with some  elements that I tried this with the src on. It simply will not work locally. The only other thing I can possibly think of is that it has a problem with the "file://" at the beginning, but I can't imagine how I would troubleshoot or avoid that. I get no errors logged.
I really can't include a reproducible example of code, but what I've done that works locally and on a live site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/styles.css">
```

and to reiterate, this doesn't work locally, but it works on a live site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/styles.css">
```

And just to clarify at the end here, the path is working when the site is live, but not locally. Not the other way around.

Comment: `rel="/stylesheet"` — The relationship type is *stylesheet* not */stylesheet*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href="/src/styles.css"` is an **absolute** path, not a relative one.

From `file:///E:/Documents/WEBSITE/things/weapons.html` it maps to something like `file:///E:/src/styles.css` (I think Windows file paths preserve the drive, but I'm not certain).

The browser has no way of knowing that you want `file:///E:/Documents/WEBSITE/` to be the root directory of the site. The root is determined by stripping all the path information off the URL, not just parts of the path.

Absolute paths are, generally, not suitable for links used on a local file system.

Use an HTTP server. There are many free ones you can use for testing. VS Code has an extension called Live Server that makes it easy to run one.

Comment: actually `/...` is a **root relative path**

Comment: @tacoshy — From [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2): A relative reference that begins with a single slash character is  termed an absolute-path reference.

Comment: Like I said in the question, I've got an `E:/src/styles.css` locally that would change something, and it doesn't.
I was under the impression that `href="/src/styles.css` would be a relative path from this page -> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp.

Comment: @mrpibb — Like I said (a) I'm not sure how Windows resolves them given the drive letter and (b) they are **not** suitable for use on `file` URLs. Your impression was wrong. `/src/styles.css` is a relative URL but an absolute path. W3Schools is dreadful.

Comment: Live Server works, thanks. Just waiting for the site to let me accept the answer.